# " Registration Sucessful" message is not showing in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django

Working on a Project"https://github.com/GargAnsh/donor_finder"  wher i am having a "donor_add_form.html" which is having a donor registration form. While saving the form it's not displaying " regitration done succesfully " though entryn are succesfully hapening in data base and page redirecting to "Donor_finder.html " also

I tried all the step, now need support to fix the problem. I also need help to expend the code further to add few feature.

Answer (score 0):

You are not retrieving messages in html.

Modify the donor_finder.html like this

```
<!-- life_saver/templates/life_saver/donor_finder.html -->

{% extends "life_saver/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% comment %} Code for showing messages {% endcomment %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <p>  {{message}}</p>
    {% endfor %}

    <h2>Find Donors by Blood Group</h2>
    <form method="get" action="{% url 'donor_finder' %}">
        <label for="{{ form.blood_group.id_for_label }}">Blood Group:</label>
        {{ form.blood_group }}
        <button type="submit">Search Donors</button>
    </form>
    


    {% if donors %}
        <h3>Matching Donors:</h3>
        <ul>
            {% for donor in donors %}
                <li>{{ donor.name }} - {{ donor.blood_group }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No matching donors found.</p>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```